# Tkinter User Input Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, user-input, tkinter-entry

I'm currently trying to make a program that takes in user input and then based on user input will compare it to another string and print out a certain output if it matches in tkinter. I have attempted to use the get method, textvariable etc., I have also looked elsewhere but it doesn't seem to work or is outdated.

```
def trebleBass():
    print(username.get())
username = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable = username)
entry2 = Entry(window)
logo = PhotoImage(file = "templogo2.png")
titleLogo = Label(window, image = logo)
titleLogo.grid(columnspan = 2)
framepackage = Frame(window)
framepackage.grid(row = 3)


label1.grid(row = 1, sticky = E)
label2.grid(row = 2, sticky = E)

entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entry2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

translate = Button(window, text = "Translate", bg = 'black', fg = 'white', 
command = trebleBass())
```

I placed a function that would just print user input just to test it out but that doesn't even work. I am somewhat new to Python, so the help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put parentheses on your `command` argument. When you put the parentheses, your passing in the return value of `trebleBass` (`None` in this case) instead of the function itself.

Just put:

```
translate = Button(window, text="Translate", bg="black", fg="white",
                   command=trebleBass)
```

Notice that the parentheses are gone at the end.

Comment: I appreciate the help, it seems like it got better somewhat but it responds "TypeError: trebleBass() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' " so  im not too sure what to do. I did put event into the function argument

Comment: Sorry remove the event from the argument list. Button commands are one of the few tkinter callbacks that don't get an event object. I was thinking of other event in tkinter. I'll remove it from the answer. So just leave the argument list empty and it should work now.